# How to compare two positions in a buffer?

Tags: vimscript

Suppose i've got two different positions in a buffer returned by `getpos()` function:

```
p1 = getpos("v")
p2 = getpos(".")
```

Is there a simple or elegant way to find out which one is before the other in the buffer?  Doing

```
if p1[1] < p2[1] || (p1[1] == p2[1] && p1[2] < p2[2])
  ...
```

each time looks ugly.

Alternatively, can i get the absolute positions -- the number of characters from the start of the file?

Comment: What are you trying to do? [(XY Problem)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/188334)

Comment: Currently i want to find out if the cursor is at the beginning or at the end of the visual selection.  But this is also a question about working with cursor positions in Vim script.  Since there is apparently no separate site about programming Vim in Vim script, i am asking it here.

Comment: Your comparison doesn't look that ugly, but to avoid rewriting it you could wrap it in a function.

Comment: Note that there might be betters solutions than comparing cursor positions if you explain what is the X problem.

Comment: The X problem is that i want to live happily, to have my Vim finely configured, and to master Vim script and all other programming languages.

Comment: On a smaller scale, i want my word-based motions in Visual mode to behave differently based on whether the cursor is at the beginning or at the end of the selection.